# How can I dissolve copper but not zinc?

Tags: electrolysis, transition-metals

I have a zinc-body garden spray head with a brass garden hose thread stuck inside.  This is actually an irritatingly common problem.

Which got me wondering: What *chemical* means exist to dissolve copper but not zinc?

(Going the other way is easy: just dipping in HCl acid dissolves the zinc but doesn't touch the copper.)

[Boiling in lime sulfur](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jRiBYMv6Tz4) will oxidize a thin layer of copper, but I don't think that will be sufficient to extract the hose thread.

[Tryggvi Emilsson](http://www.theodoregray.com/PeriodicTable/Elements/030/index.html) supposedly used KCN and $\ce{K2S2O8}$ to dissolve copper without touching zinc, but claims it was a very tricky process to get right.

Is there a clever way to extract the copper using electrolysis?$%edit$

Comment: Your main problem is that zinc is much more reactive than copper, so it is very hard to come up with something that creates some copper ion but not a zinc ion.

Comment: Alternatively, try heating to separate the parts. The thermal expansion coefficient for zinc is about $\alpha=30\times10^{-6}\ \mathrm K^{-1}$, whereas the value for brass is about $\alpha=19\times10^{-6}\ \mathrm K^{-1}$.

Comment: If it is worth the trouble, you might saw three cuts through the copper hose fitting (which will also make notches in the threads of the zinc female fitting). You can then try to pry the sections of the copper male fitting out. However, the odds are that the zinc is corroded and bonded to the copper. Next time, you might coat the threads with grease or soft wax to discourage electrolytic corrosion. It's not a *chemistry* answer, but **much** safer than using cyanides.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik - Indeed; good practical answer.  That is how I generally solve this sort of problem.  I'm just a little surprised there's no reliable way to attack copper without hurting zinc.   (Or maybe cyanides *are* reliable and the authors of that process just wanted to discourage people from "casually" attempting it?  Because of course I keep a good stock of KCN at home ready to open up every time I get copper stuck to zinc ;)

Comment: Brass is an alloy of copper and zinc. you dissolve the alloy and may possibly precipitate zinc. Of  course it will not be in the from of a spray fitting. We very rarely saw dezincification of brass in the refinery;  never did figure out exactly how it occurred.

Comment: H2S reacts with the copper in Monel metal over the nickel but the metals are intimately mixed. The best suggestion is probably the careful application of heat and /or cold. If corrosion is the cause soaking in a strong ammonia solution might dissolve the interface corrosion.